# How to read a Nested JSON in Spark Scala?

Tags: json, scala, apache-spark

Here is my Nested JSON file.

```
{
"dc_id": "dc-101",
"source": {
    "sensor-igauge": {
      "id": 10,
      "ip": "68.28.91.22",
      "description": "Sensor attached to the container ceilings",
      "temp":35,
      "c02_level": 1475,
      "geo": {"lat":38.00, "long":97.00}                        
    },
    "sensor-ipad": {
      "id": 13,
      "ip": "67.185.72.1",
      "description": "Sensor ipad attached to carbon cylinders",
      "temp": 34,
      "c02_level": 1370,
      "geo": {"lat":47.41, "long":-122.00}
    },
    "sensor-inest": {
      "id": 8,
      "ip": "208.109.163.218",
      "description": "Sensor attached to the factory ceilings",
      "temp": 40,
      "c02_level": 1346,
      "geo": {"lat":33.61, "long":-111.89}
    },
    "sensor-istick": {
      "id": 5,
      "ip": "204.116.105.67",
      "description": "Sensor embedded in exhaust pipes in the ceilings",
      "temp": 40,
      "c02_level": 1574,
      "geo": {"lat":35.93, "long":-85.46}
    }
  }
}
```

How can I read the JSON file into Dataframe with Spark Scala. There is no array object in the JSON file, so I can't use explode. Can anyone help?

Comment: How do you want to see your data, as a single record or 4 records? Can you show one example record?

Comment: 4 records will be good.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
val df = spark.read.option("multiline", true).json("data/test.json")

df
  .select(col("dc_id"), explode(array("source.*")) as "level1")
  .withColumn("id", col("level1.id"))
  .withColumn("ip", col("level1.ip"))
  .withColumn("temp", col("level1.temp"))
  .withColumn("description", col("level1.description"))
  .withColumn("c02_level", col("level1.c02_level"))
  .withColumn("lat", col("level1.geo.lat"))
  .withColumn("long", col("level1.geo.long"))
  .drop("level1")
  .show(false)
```

*Sample Output:*

```
+------+---+---------------+----+------------------------------------------------+---------+-----+-------+
|dc_id |id |ip             |temp|description                                     |c02_level|lat  |long   |
+------+---+---------------+----+------------------------------------------------+---------+-----+-------+
|dc-101|10 |68.28.91.22    |35  |Sensor attached to the container ceilings       |1475     |38.0 |97.0   |
|dc-101|8  |208.109.163.218|40  |Sensor attached to the factory ceilings         |1346     |33.61|-111.89|
|dc-101|13 |67.185.72.1    |34  |Sensor ipad attached to carbon cylinders        |1370     |47.41|-122.0 |
|dc-101|5  |204.116.105.67 |40  |Sensor embedded in exhaust pipes in the ceilings|1574     |35.93|-85.46 |
+------+---+---------------+----+------------------------------------------------+---------+-----+-------+
```

Instead of selecting each column, you can try writing some generic UDF to get all the individual columns.

*Note:* Tested with Spark 2.3

Comment: Thanks a lot sir!

Comment: @Bhima Rao Gogineni why are you passing false in show()

Comment: @Abhinay By default, parameter `truncate = true` to Spark data frame show function. To avoid the truncation of long string columns, I am just passing `truncate = false`.

Answer (score 1):

Taken the string into a variable called jsonString

```
import org.apache.spark.sql._
import spark.implicits._
val df = spark.read.json(Seq(jsonString).toDS)
val df1 = df.withColumn("lat" ,explode(array("source.sensor-igauge.geo.lat")))
```

You can follow the same steps for other structures as well - map/ array structures

Comment: Can't it be generic? Like if I'm mentioning the array names for exploding, then I need to know the file itself, so it is like hardcoding. 
If I am loading some random JSON files, then we can not print the JSON putting that into a Dataset?

Answer (score 0):

```
val df = spark.read.option("multiline", true).json("myfile.json")

df.select($"dc_id", explode(array("source.*")))
.select($"dc_id", $"col.c02_level", $"col.description", $"col.geo.lat", $"col.geo.long", $"col.id", $"col.ip", $"col.temp")
.show(false)
```

Output:

```
+------+---------+------------------------------------------------+-----+-------+---+---------------+----+
|dc_id |c02_level|description                                     |lat  |long   |id |ip             |temp|
+------+---------+------------------------------------------------+-----+-------+---+---------------+----+
|dc-101|1475     |Sensor attached to the container ceilings       |38.0 |97.0   |10 |68.28.91.22    |35  |
|dc-101|1346     |Sensor attached to the factory ceilings         |33.61|-111.89|8  |208.109.163.218|40  |
|dc-101|1370     |Sensor ipad attached to carbon cylinders        |47.41|-122.0 |13 |67.185.72.1    |34  |
|dc-101|1574     |Sensor embedded in exhaust pipes in the ceilings|35.93|-85.46 |5  |204.116.105.67 |40  |
+------+---------+------------------------------------------------+-----+-------+---+---------------+----+
```