# Processing List of nested column in spark huge dataframe in scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, user-defined-functions

I want to store list of nested `json` in `spark dataframe`, and also wanted to process that column. There is also the need for operations like update on some value or delete.

```
    {
      "studentName": "abc",
      "mailId": "abc@gmail.com",
      "class" : 7,
      "scoreBoard" : [
        {"subject":"Math","score":90,"grade":"A"},
        {"subject":"Science","score":82,"grade":"A"},
        {"subject":"History","score":80,"grade":"A"},
        {"subject":"Hindi","score":75,"grade":"B"},
        {"subject":"English","score":80,"grade":"A"},
        {"subject":"Geography","score":80,"grade":"A"},
      ]
    }
```

Trying to process **scoreBoard** field from above data, find out top five subject, delete lowest score subject row, also change grade of some subject.

```scala
    case class Student(subject: String, score: Long, grade : String)
    
    var studentTest = sc.read.json("**/testStudent.json")

    val studentSchema = ArrayType(new StructType().add("subject", StringType).add("score", LongType).add("grade", StringType))

    val parseStudentUDF = udf((scoreBoard : Seq[Row]) => {
     //do data processing  and return updated data
     ListBuffer(Subtable(subject,score,grade), , ,)
    }, subtableSchema)


    studentTest = studentTest.withColumn("scoreBoard",parseStudentUDF(col("scoreBoard")))
```

I am not sure how to convert `seq[Row]` to `DataFrame` in `UDF`, or how to process seq to sort data and delete any row.

Is there any way to do this?

Any different approach also acceptable.

Comment: [nested json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53755959/how-to-read-a-nested-json-in-spark-scala)! - example read nested json in spark scala

Comment: @mvasyliv Not sure how to process data (of 1000 users) after creating new columns. Like I want to update particular students subject grade by comparing with other.. and at the end data should be in same format. can we process data by grouping the rows?

Answer (score 1):

this approach is using Spark dataframes and Spark SQL. I hope this can help you.

```
package tests

import org.apache.log4j.{Level, Logger}
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession

object ProcessingList {
  val spark = SparkSession
    .builder()
    .appName("ProcessingList")
    .master("local[*]")
    .config("spark.sql.shuffle.partitions","4") //Change to a more reasonable default number of partitions for our data
    .config("spark.app.id","ProcessingList") // To silence Metrics warning
    .getOrCreate()

  val sc = spark.sparkContext

  val sqlContext = spark.sqlContext

  val input = "/home/cloudera/files/tests/list_processing.json"

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    Logger.getRootLogger.setLevel(Level.ERROR)

    try {

      import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

      val studentTest = sqlContext
        .read
        .json(input)

      studentTest
        .filter(col("grade").isNotNull)
        .select(col("grade"), col("score"), col("subject"))
        .cache()
        .createOrReplaceTempView("student_test")

      sqlContext
          .sql(
            """SELECT grade, score, subject
              |FROM student_test
              |ORDER BY score DESC
              |LIMIT 5
              |""".stripMargin)
          .show()

      // To have the opportunity to view the web console of Spark: http://localhost:4041/
      println("Type whatever to the console to exit......")
      scala.io.StdIn.readLine()
    } finally {
      sc.stop()
      println("SparkContext stopped")
      spark.stop()
      println("SparkSession stopped")
    }
  }
}
```

```
+-----+-----+---------+
|grade|score|  subject|
+-----+-----+---------+
|    A|   90|     Math|
|    A|   82|  Science|
|    A|   80|  History|
|    A|   80|  English|
|    A|   80|Geography|
+-----+-----+---------+
```

Regards.

Comment: Not sure how to process data (of 1000 users) after creating new columns. Like I want to update particular students subject grade by comparing with other.. and at the end data should be in same format. can we process data by grouping the rows?

Comment: I think so, but you must be more clear, what output do you expect?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61183314/how-to-process-array-of-json-column-in-spark-sql-dataframe .... here I asked new Que with Input and Expected output..

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, the comment by mvasyliv is good in my opinion.

To modify it, you can use

- plain scala collection methods like .filter(), however you dont need spark for that. See Scala collections API on how to use
- You can write UnaryTransformers, which transform specific columns and insert a new one. See this simple Special Chars remover as an example. Notice the outputDataType method and createTransformFunc, which is based on .map collection method.

  ```
  class SpecialCharsRemover (override val uid: String)
  extends UnaryTransformer[Seq[String], Seq[String], SpecialCharsRemover]         with DefaultParamsWritable {

    def this() = this(Identi



  fiable.randomUID("tokenPermutationGenerato

  r"))

  override protected def createTransformFunc: Seq[String] => Seq[String] =     (tokensWithSpecialChars: Seq[String]) => {

  tokensWithSpecialChars.map(token => {
        removeSpecialCharsImpl(token)
      })
    }

    private def removeSpecialCharsImpl(token: String): String =  {
      if(token.equals("")) {
        return

   ""
  }

  //remove sonderzeichen
  var tempToken = token;

  tempToken = tempToken.replace(",", "")
  tempToken = tempToken.replace("'", "")
  tempToken = tempToken.replace("'", "")
  tempToken = tempToken.replace("_", "")
  tempToken = tempToken.replace("-", "")
  tempToken = tempToken.replace("!", "")
  tempToken = tempToken.replace(".", "")
  tempToken = tempToken.replace("?", "")
  tempToken = tempToken.replace(":", "")
  tempToken = tempToken.replace(")", "")
  tempToken = tempToken.replace("(", "")
  tempToken = tempToken.replace(",", "")
  tempToken = tempToken.replace("‘", "")
  tempToken = tempToken.replace("}", "")
  tempToken = tempToken.replace("{", "")
  tempToken = tempToken.replace("[", "")
  tempToken = tempToken.replace("]", "")
  tempToken = tempToken.replace("]", "")
  tempToken = tempToken.replace("®", "")

  tempToken = ThesaurusUtils.stemToken(tempToken);

  tempToken
  }

  override protected def outputDataType: DataType = new ArrayType(StringType,     false)
  }
  ```

Or you can register an arbitrary function as an UDF (Java Code):

```
  ds.sparkSession().sqlContext().udf().register("THE_BOB", (UDF1<String, String>) this::getSomeBob, DataTypes.StringType); 

 private String getSomeBob(String text) {
        return "bob";
    }
```

then call it with:

```
   bobColumn = functions.callUDF("THE_BOB", bobColumn);
```