# How to Process array of json column in spark sql dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Input Json

```
{"studentName": "abc","mailId": "abc@gmail.com","class" : 7,"newSub" : "Environment","grade" : "A","score"  : 95,"scoreBoard" : [{"subject":"Math","score":90,"grade":"A"},{"subject":"Science","score":82,"grade":"A"},{"subject":"History","score":80,"grade":"A"},{"subject":"Hindi","score":75,"grade":"B"}, {"subject":"English","score":80,"grade":"A"},{"subject":"Geography","score":80,"grade":"A"}]}
{"studentName": "xyz","mailId": "xyz@gmail.com","class" : 8,"newSub" : "Environment","grade" : "A","score"  : 95,"scoreBoard" : [{"subject":"Math","score":90,"grade":"A"},{"subject":"Physics","score":85,"grade":"A"},{"subject":"Chemistry","score":80,"grade":"A"},{"subject":"Hindi","score":75,"grade":"B"},{"subject":"English","score":70,"grade":"B"},{"subject":"Biology","score":87,"grade":"A"}]}
{"studentName": "efg","mailId": "efg@gmail.com","class" : 9,"newSub" : "Environment","grade" : "A","score"  : 95,"scoreBoard" : [{"subject":"Math","score":91,"grade":"A"},{"subject":"Physics","score":77,"grade":"B"},{"subject":"Chemistry","score":72,"grade":"B"},{"subject":"Computer","score":95,"grade":"A"},{"subject":"English","score":82,"grade":"A"},{"subject":"Biology","score":76,"grade":"B"}]}

+-----+-----+-------------+-----------+-----+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------+
|class|grade|mailId       |newSub     |score|scoreBoard                                                                                      |studentName|
+-----+-----+-------------+-----------+-----+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------+
|7    |A    |abc@gmail.com|Environment|95   |[[A,90,Math], [A,82,Science], [A,80,History], [B,75,Hindi], [A,80,English], [A,80,Geography]]   |abc        |
|8    |A    |xyz@gmail.com|Environment|95   |[[A,90,Math], [A,85,Physics], [A,80,Chemistry], [B,75,Hindi], [B,70,English], [A,87,Biology]]   |xyz        |
|9    |A    |efg@gmail.com|Environment|95   |[[A,91,Math], [B,77,Physics], [B,72,Chemistry], [A,95,Computer], [A,82,English], [B,76,Biology]]|efg        |
+-----+-----+-------------+-----------+-----+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------+
```

Processing I want -

1. add  newSub's json is scoreBoard list (read data from user row - newSub, score, grade)
2. sort them on score and remove the json from scoreBoard list having less score

Expected output -

```
{"studentName": "abc","mailId": "abc@gmail.com","class" : 7,"scoreBoard" : [{"subject":"Environment","score":95,"grade":"A"},{"subject":"Math","score":90,"grade":"A"},{"subject":"Science","score":82,"grade":"A"},{"subject":"History","score":80,"grade":"A"},{"subject":"English","score":80,"grade":"A"},{"subject":"Geography","score":80,"grade":"A"}]}
{"studentName": "xyz","mailId": "xyz@gmail.com","class" : 8,"scoreBoard" : [{"subject":"Environment","score":95,"grade":"A"},{"subject":"Math","score":90,"grade":"A"},{"subject":"Physics","score":85,"grade":"A"},{"subject":"Chemistry","score":80,"grade":"A"},{"subject":"Hindi","score":75,"grade":"B"},{"subject":"Biology","score":87,"grade":"A"}]}
{"studentName": "efg","mailId": "efg@gmail.com","class" : 9,"scoreBoard" : [{"subject":"Environment","score":95,"grade":"A"},{"subject":"Math","score":91,"grade":"A"},{"subject":"Physics","score":77,"grade":"B"},{"subject":"Computer","score":95,"grade":"A"},{"subject":"English","score":82,"grade":"A"},{"subject":"Biology","score":76,"grade":"B"}]}

+-----+-------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------+
|class|mailId       |scoreBoard                                                                                         |studentName|
+-----+-------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------+
|7    |abc@gmail.com|[[A,95,Environment], [A,90,Math], [A,82,Science], [A,80,History], [A,80,English], [A,80,Geography]]|abc        |
|8    |xyz@gmail.com|[[A,95,Environment], [A,90,Math], [A,85,Physics], [A,80,Chemistry], [B,75,Hindi], [A,87,Biology]]  |xyz        |
|9    |efg@gmail.com|[[A,95,Environment], [A,91,Math], [B,77,Physics], [A,95,Computer], [A,82,English], [B,76,Biology]] |efg        |
+-----+-------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------+
```

I tried

1st way - UDF processing but Sorting and deleting json from scoreBoard column in UDF is challenging

2nd way - explode the column scoreBoard, got 6 row for single student, each for every subject. Challenge I am facing in this is, how to process data group wise, Like how to add new row for new Subject,sort each user's subject score and delete one row.

Need help to select way to solve this problem, if anyone know is there any new/different efficient way to do the same processing.
Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 import ss.implicits._

  val schema = new ArrayType(new StructType(Array(
    StructField("grade",DataTypes.StringType,true),
    StructField("score",DataTypes.LongType,true),
    StructField("subject",DataTypes.StringType,true))),true)

  def addValue = udf((array: Seq[Row], newval:Row)=> array ++ Array(newval),schema)

  def sortAndRemove = udf((array: Seq[Row])=> array.sortBy(x=>x.getAs[Long]("score"))(Ordering[Long].reverse).slice(0,array.length-1),schema)

val df2 =  df.withColumn("map_col",struct(col("grade"),col("score"),col("newSub").as("subject")))
    .withColumn("scoreBoard",sortAndRemove(addValue(col("scoreBoard"),col("map_col"))))
  df2.select("scoreBoard").show(false)
```

UDF approach, where ss is SparkSession. addvalue can be replaced with array_union if using spark version 2.4 and above.

Above code will work for spark 2.0 and above

Comment: if there is epoch day attr also in the schema along with grade,score,Subject. -> {"studentName": "abc","mailId": "abc@gmail.com","class" : 7,"newSub" : "Environment","grade" : "A","score"  : 95,"currentDay" : "18358","scoreBoard" : [{"subject":"Math","score":90,"grade":"A","day": "18340"},{"subject":"Science","score":82,"grade":"A","day": "18354"},{"subject":"History","score":80,"grade":"A","day": "18355"},{"subject":"Environment","score":95,"grade":"A","day": "18356"}, {"subject":"English","score":80,"grade":"A","day": "18356"},{"subject":"Geography","score":80,"grade":"A","day": "18356"}]}

Comment: |class|currentDay|grade|mailId       |newSub     |score|scoreBoard                                                                                                                             |studentName|
+-----+----------+-----+-------------+-----------+-----+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------+
|7 |18358 |A |abc@gmail.com|Environment|95   |[[18340,A,90,Math], [18354,A,82,Science], [18355,A,80,History], [18356,A,95,Environment], [18356,A,80,English], [18356,A,80,Geography]]|abc|

Comment: 1. If score of new sub is same as scoreBoard like  Environment has 95 in cilumn ans also in scoreBoard then, I don't want to add new column

2. I want to compare all the days with currentDay column and scoreBoard entries which are older than 10 day from currentDay.. I want to delete them (there may be 1 / 2 / n or No old record for deletion) here day = 18340 are old and want to delete those entries..


Is this possible??How can I achieve this using UDF

Thanks In advance...

Comment: you can modify sort & delete udf

Answer (score 0):

This approach is using `Spark dataframes/datasets` and `Spark SQL`.

```scala
import org.apache.log4j.{Level, Logger}
import org.apache.spark.sql.{Row, SparkSession}

object ProcessingList {
  val spark = SparkSession
    .builder()
    .appName("ProcessingList")
    .master("local[*]")
    .config("spark.sql.shuffle.partitions","4") //Change to a more reasonable default number of partitions for our data
    .config("spark.app.id","ProcessingList") // To silence Metrics warning
    .getOrCreate()

  val sc = spark.sparkContext

  val sqlContext = spark.sqlContext

  val input = "/home/cloudera/files/tests/list_processing.json"

  case class Student(cl: Long, grade: String,mail : String,ns: String,score: Long,sbGrade: String, sbScore: Long,sbSubject: String, name: String)

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    Logger.getRootLogger.setLevel(Level.ERROR)

    try {
      import spark.implicits._

      val studentTest = sqlContext
        .read
        .json(input)
        .flatMap(r => r.getSeq(5).map( (sq: Row)  => Student(r.getLong(0), r.getString(1), r.getString(2), r.getString(3), r.getLong(4),sq.getString(0),sq.getLong(1), sq.getString(2), r.getString(6)))).as[Student]
        .cache()

      studentTest.show(truncate = false)

      studentTest.createOrReplaceTempView("student_test")

      sqlContext
          .sql(
            """
              |SELECT cl, grade, mail,ns, score, 
              |RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY cl ORDER BY sbScore DESC) AS ranking, 
              |sbGrade,sbScore, sbSubject, name
              |FROM student_test
              |ORDER BY cl
              |""".stripMargin)
          .show(truncate = false)


      // To have the opportunity to view the web console of Spark: http://localhost:4041/
      println("Type whatever to the console to exit......")
      scala.io.StdIn.readLine()
    } finally {
      sc.stop()
      println("SparkContext stopped")
      spark.stop()
      println("SparkSession stopped")
    }
  }
}
```

and expected results

```
+---+-----+-------------+-----------+-----+------+-------+-------+---------+----+
|cl |grade|mail         |ns         |score|points|sbGrade|sbScore|sbSubject|name|
+---+-----+-------------+-----------+-----+------+-------+-------+---------+----+
|7  |A    |abc@gmail.com|Environment|95   |1     |A      |90     |Math     |abc |
|7  |A    |abc@gmail.com|Environment|95   |2     |A      |82     |Science  |abc |
|7  |A    |abc@gmail.com|Environment|95   |3     |A      |80     |History  |abc |
|7  |A    |abc@gmail.com|Environment|95   |3     |A      |80     |English  |abc |
|7  |A    |abc@gmail.com|Environment|95   |3     |A      |80     |Geography|abc |
|7  |A    |abc@gmail.com|Environment|95   |6     |B      |75     |Hindi    |abc |
|8  |A    |xyz@gmail.com|Environment|95   |1     |A      |90     |Math     |xyz |
|8  |A    |xyz@gmail.com|Environment|95   |2     |A      |87     |Biology  |xyz |
|8  |A    |xyz@gmail.com|Environment|95   |3     |A      |85     |Physics  |xyz |
|8  |A    |xyz@gmail.com|Environment|95   |4     |A      |80     |Chemistry|xyz |
|8  |A    |xyz@gmail.com|Environment|95   |5     |B      |75     |Hindi    |xyz |
|8  |A    |xyz@gmail.com|Environment|95   |6     |B      |70     |English  |xyz |
|9  |A    |efg@gmail.com|Environment|95   |1     |A      |95     |Computer |efg |
|9  |A    |efg@gmail.com|Environment|95   |2     |A      |91     |Math     |efg |
|9  |A    |efg@gmail.com|Environment|95   |3     |A      |82     |English  |efg |
|9  |A    |efg@gmail.com|Environment|95   |4     |B      |77     |Physics  |efg |
|9  |A    |efg@gmail.com|Environment|95   |5     |B      |76     |Biology  |efg |
|9  |A    |efg@gmail.com|Environment|95   |6     |B      |72     |Chemistry|efg |
+---+-----+-------------+-----------+-----+------+-------+-------+---------+----+
```